# Load image in ajax query (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I make ajax call and return json from back end

Here is code of ajax call

```
<script>
$('#search').click(function () {
   $("#patients").empty();
   var lname = $("#lname").val();

     var model = {
         LastName: lname
     };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ResultOfSearch", "PatientDatabase")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var list = data;

            //alert(list);
            var listnumber = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
                var arrow  = '@Url.Content("~/images/doc-50.png")';
                var patientsList = ' <td class="point">' +
                    (i+1) +
                     '</td>' +
                    '<td class="title"> ' +
                    list[i].dateOfBirthday +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td class="title"> ' +
                    list[i].firstName +
                    '</td>' + '<td>' + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:end;>' + arrow + '</td>';
                $("#patients").append('<tr>' + patientsList + '</tr>');
            };
        }
    });
});
```

In this row i try  to  show image

```
+ '<td style="text-align:end;>' + arrow + '</td>';
```

Image is in arrow value `var arrow  = '@Url.Content("~/images/doc-50.png")';`

But it not showing. I have no errors in console related to image.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an image tag inside the `td` and then use `arrow` as the `src` attribute of the image because `@Url.Content` is used when you wish to resolve a url for any file or resource on your site and you would pass it the relative path, it returns the application absolute path for the file.

like below

```
'<td style="text-align:end;"><img src=' + arrow + '/></td>';
```

BTW which version of .NET MVC are you using? for mvc 4 and above you can directly use relative url in image as src="~/images/doc-50.png"

Comment: I tried also directly set path like ` <img src="~/images/icons8-Delete-50.png"/>`. But it not show image  too

Comment: @mark_spencer can you post the generated HTML of the table in your question ? as of MVC 4 you can directly use image path with `~` without @Url helper

Comment: It very strange, but it not generate last `td`

Comment: hm. seems I found problem

Comment: `<td style="text-align:end;>` I miss `"` in end of style attribute

Comment: @mark_spencer updated my answer and you can directly use `var arrow = "~/images/doc-50.png";`

Comment: It's stange but I get this `http://localhost:51091/images/icons8-Delete-50.png/` not found.

But I get image in images folder

Comment: for `doc-50` same thing

Comment: Solved my problem